# Issues with groupby and aggregate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This is my code:

```
df['PV_SUM'] = df.groupby('DOCKET').agg({'PV':sum})
```

is not returning any results, just an empty series.

This is my hypothetical dataframe:

```
DOCKET    PV
1a        1
1a        1 
1a        1
1b        0
1b        1
1b        1
```

and this is the result i'm looking for:

```
DOCKET    PV      PV_SUM
1a        1         3
1a        1         3
1a        1         3
1b        0         2
1b        1         2
1b        1         2
```

what am i doing wrong? The dtypes for DOCKET is object and the dtype for PV is float. I've changed the dtype to PV to int but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) instead:

```
df['PV_SUM'] = df.groupby('DOCKET').PV.transform(sum)
```

Output:

```
  DOCKET  PV  PV_SUM
0     1a   1       3
1     1a   1       3
2     1a   1       3
3     1b   0       2
4     1b   1       2
5     1b   1       2
```

---

The issue with your code is that `df.groupby('DOCKET').agg({'PV':sum})` returns a dataframe with `DOCKET` as index and `PV` as value column. When you try assigning it back to the daframe, pandas looks for matching indexes, and, since there are no matchs, it returns `NaN`.

For example, take a look at the output from `df.groupby('DOCKET').agg({'PV':sum})`:

```
        PV
DOCKET    
1a       3
1b       2
```

As pandas matches the index, you could first set the index of your dataframe to "DOCKET", then it will work as expected:

```py
result = df.groupby('DOCKET').agg({'PV':sum})
df = df.set_index('DOCKET')
df['PV_SUM'] = result
```

Comment: thank you! this was driving me insane. can you explain why my solution wasn't working?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a bit of explanation. Pandas usually works with index labels. Let me know if it's clear enough. Best!